# For positive integer numbers, so $\min\{\frac{c}{a},\frac{c}{b}\}+\lfloor\frac{c}{a}\rfloor\lfloor\frac{c}{b}\rfloor\geqq c\lfloor\frac{c}{ab}\rfloor$

Tags: number-theory, maxima-minima, integers

> Given three positive integer numbers $a, b, c$. Prove that
>   $$\min\left \{ \frac{c}{a}, \frac{c}{b} \right \}+ \left \lfloor \frac{c}{a} \right \rfloor\left \lfloor \frac{c}{b} \right \rfloor\geqq c\left \lfloor \frac{c}{ab} \right \rfloor$$

I think midway calculations are not easy formulas, I can't find what kind of formula transformation to solve! So I need to the help! Thanks for all the nice comments and interests from MathematicsSE-ees!

Comment: You can assume $a \le b$. Also, why the curly brackets with min?

Comment: Oh! We also can use $\min$ with the curly brackets in some countries! I'll notice that! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inequality requested to be proven is

$$\min\left( \frac{c}{a}, \frac{c}{b} \right) + \left\lfloor \frac{c}{a} \right\rfloor \left\lfloor \frac{c}{b} \right\rfloor \geqq c\left\lfloor \frac{c}{ab} \right\rfloor \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Since it's symmetric in $a$ and $b$, WLOG let $b \ge a$, so

$$\min\left(\frac{c}{a},\frac{c}{b}\right) = \frac{c}{b} \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Let

$$c = kab + d, \; k \ge 0, \; 0 \le d \lt ab \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

The RHS of \eqref{eq1} becomes

$$c\left \lfloor \frac{c}{ab} \right \rfloor = (kab + d)(k) = abk^2 + kd \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

Consider the case of $c \lt b$. This means $\left\lfloor \frac{c}{a} \right\rfloor \left\lfloor \frac{c}{b} \right\rfloor = 0$ and, since $a \ge 1$, also $c\left\lfloor \frac{c}{ab} \right\rfloor = 0$. Since $\frac{c}{b} \gt 0$, this means \eqref{eq1} holds with a strict inequality.

Otherwise, with $c \ge b$ (so $\frac{c}{a}$ and $\frac{c}{b}$ are each $\ge 1$, allowing the inequality below to subtract $1$ from each value and still have them be non-negative numbers), using \eqref{eq2}, the LHS of \eqref{eq1} becomes

\begin{align}
\frac{c}{b} + \left\lfloor \frac{c}{a} \right\rfloor \left\lfloor \frac{c}{b} \right\rfloor & = ka + \frac{d}{b} + \left\lfloor kb + \frac{d}{a} \right\rfloor \left\lfloor ka + \frac{d}{b} \right\rfloor \\
& \gt ka + \frac{d}{b} + \left(kb + \frac{d}{a} - 1\right)\left(ka + \frac{d}{b} - 1\right) \\
& = ka + \frac{d}{b} + abk^2 + kd - kb + kd + \frac{d^2}{ab} - \frac{d}{a} - ka - \frac{d}{b} + 1 \\
& = abk^2 + kd + \left(-kb + kd + \frac{d^2}{ab} - \frac{d}{a} + 1\right) \\
& = abk^2 + kd + \left(k(d-b) + \frac{d}{a}\left(\frac{d}{b} - 1\right) + 1\right) \tag{5}\label{eq5}
\end{align}

If $d \ge b$, then $k(d-b) + \frac{d}{a}\left(\frac{d}{b} - 1\right) + 1 \ge 1$, so the RHS of \eqref{eq5} is greater than that of \eqref{eq4}, meaning \eqref{eq1} holds with the strict inequality.

Next, consider the case where $d \lt b$. Let

$$d = ma + n, \; m \ge 0, \; 0 \le n \lt a \tag{6}\label{eq6}$$

Now, starting from the RHS of the first line of \eqref{eq5}, this gives

\begin{align}
ka + \frac{d}{b} + \left\lfloor kb + \frac{d}{a} \right\rfloor \left\lfloor ka + \frac{d}{b} \right\rfloor & = ka + \frac{d}{b} + (kb + m)(ka) \\
& \ge ka + (kb + m)(ka) \\
& = ka + abk^2 + mka \\
& = abk^2 + k(ma + a) \\
& \ge abk^2 + k(ma + n) \\
& = abk^2 + kd \tag{7}\label{eq7}
\end{align}

Once again, this shows that \eqref{eq1} holds. Note the only possibility for the first inequality in \eqref{eq7} to be an equals is if $d = 0$ since it's ignoring the $\frac{d}{b}$ term. Also, the only possibility of the second equality to be an equals is if $k = 0$ since $a \gt n$. Thus, both can be equals only if $k = d = 0$, but then this gives $c = 0$ in \eqref{eq3}, but the problem says $c \gt 0$. Thus, once again, it's a strict inequality in \eqref{eq1}.

As all possible cases have been considered, this shows \eqref{eq1} is always true, with it actually always having the LHS $\gt$ RHS.

Comment: I think the first inequality in the equation $(7)$ is an equality, and the second inequality is strict, since $a>n$ by the choice of $n$, so that in the second case the inequality is still strict, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @awllower The first inequality in equation (7) is an inequality since if $d \gt 0$, then $\frac{d}{b} \gt 0$. I'm ignoring that term on the right side because it's less than $1$ due to considering the case $d \lt b$. As for the second inequality, you're correct that $a \gt n$, but I also need to consider the possibility that $k = 0$.

Comment: @awllower I started thinking more about what you wrote to realize the last set of inequalities are actually, overall, a strict one. This shows the OP's question is actually true using just $\gt$.

Comment: Indeed I forgot the case $k=0$, which can be dealt with separately: $\min(\frac ca,\frac cb)>0$. And in the first inequality we are only considering the fractional parts, so $\frac db$ and $\frac na$ are ignored.